# Creating set of maps (PDF) using QGIS and Python with WMS Data

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, wms, print-composer

For a scientific project I am trying to create a set of PDFs in QGIS with a fix layout (in the print composer) but per PDF a) different map item attributes (extents) and b) a QR-code to identify this PDF. The QR-Codes are already created with a python module (-> .svg) and the extents of the map items are a simple raster. The map content is a WMS which is embedded in the QGIS project.

My idea is to open a pre-defined print composer, iterate through the raster (has simple coordinates) and generate a PDF per iteration with the actual a) map layout and b) QR-code.

I am working with QGIS 2.12.1 (uses Pyton 2.7.5)

Comment: When you say "iterate through the raster", do you mean pan/zoom to different areas of it in the composer?

Comment: We've done similar bulk print to pdf for the selected features in SurveyingCalculation plugin. It is available in the QGIS plugin repository. See batch plotting.py and batch_plotting_dialog.py

Comment: Right, I mean to pan to different areas. And I will have a look at this plugin, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Finally I created the PDFs with the atlas plugin in the print composer of QGIS. In the atlas configuration I set my shapefile as covering layer and used a dynamic expression for the filename like

```
'Map_'|| x_min(@atlas_geometry) || '_' || y_min(@atlas_geometry) || '_' || "SCALE"
```

The QR-Codes I generated before are shown as an image with an also dynamic expression, in this form

```
to_string( 'C:\\......\\' || x_min( @atlas_geometry ) || '_'|| y_min( @atlas_geometry ) || '_5000.svg')
```

for the scale 1:5000. Both worked pretty fine and took its time (about 3 days for the 20'000 maps).
Actually my problem is:
The printed WMS data (especially the fonts) are too small, the output (PDF or image) doesn't look like the preview in the print composer (see 2 screenshots). I just used the "export to pdf" function without chaning any settings.
How can I get the output scaled like in the preview?
[image: output]
[image: preview]